# Predicting states in Machine Learning using RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras, recurrent-neural-network

As of late I have been trying to predict state of a user using Recurrent Neural Network on the data-set of posts by a particular user that I got from REDDIT, but I am not able to understand what do I need to input.

For example there is a user who wants to buy a mobile and I want to predict state of the user that is whether he is **state: 1 (thinking about buying new phone) state: 2 (bought a new phone) state: 3 (Regret after buying)** based on his previous reddit posts. As far as I have understood I think it involves time series analysis. I am not just able to understand what kind of data-structure do I need to input to train the RNN and how to to actually implement RNN in this case. If there is a better way or some other time-series classifier appropriate please put some light.

So far I am able to follow up a tutorial (http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) using keras but it teaches me how to do it by just classifying the reviews (positive/negative). Also, as each post is independent of each other, but in my case each purchase is dependent on other purchase.

I have data in JSON format where I have manually defined **state** (key) which I am using as a class label as can be seen here-under:

States are defined as: 
**state: 1 (thinking about buying new phone)
state: 2 (bought a new phone)
state: 3 (Regret after buying)**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596ffc2423900a52fb2fb077"),
    "redditor" : "boughtSamsungGalaxy8",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "state" : 1,
            "created_at" : 146532030908.0,
            "title" : "Did I do the right thing",
            "num_comments" : 7,
            "downs" : 0,
            "manual_annotation_done" : 1,
            "subreddit" : "mobilePhonePurchase",
            "score" : 7,
            "post_type" : 5,
            "post" : "Guys I am planning to buy a new phone, which one should I buy? Please give me valuable suggestions",
            "ups" : 7,
            "id" : "598Qc"
        }
    ],
    "manual_annotation_done" : 1
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596ffc2423900a52fb2fb077"),
    "redditor" : "boughtSamsungGalaxy8",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "state" : 2,
            "created_at" : 146532030908.0,
            "title" : "I bought the phone will review it next week",
            "num_comments" : 7,
            "downs" : 0,
            "manual_annotation_done" : 1,
            "subreddit" : "mobilePhonePurchase",
            "score" : 7,
            "post_type" : 5,
            "post" : "Hello everyone I finalised on xyz phone and I am thinking to review it after a week or so. Let me get my hands dirty on them!",
            "ups" : 7,
            "id" : "598Qc"
        }
    ],
    "manual_annotation_done" : 1
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596ffc2423900a52fb2fb077"),
    "redditor" : "boughtSamsungGalaxy8",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "state" : 3,
            "created_at" : 146532030908.0,
            "title" : "Did I do the right thing",
            "num_comments" : 7,
            "downs" : 0,
            "manual_annotation_done" : 1,
            "subreddit" : "mobilePhonePurchase",
            "score" : 7,
            "post_type" : 5,
            "post" : "As I write I am messed up the mobile phone heats, its a bomb in the hands",
            "ups" : 7,
            "id" : "598Qc"
        }
    ],
    "manual_annotation_done" : 1
}
```

Now I need to predict the states based on the state number that I manually annotated.

I am confused how to go about it. As I am fairly new to machine learning any insights will help me. If you know of any tutorial which does that?

Input for this model will be: Post and Comment (Bag of words). Label will be the annotated state.

Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest you revisit the fundamentals of machine learning and neural networks before attempting this project. An RNN is a complex form of a neural net and is not, in my opinion, required for this project. You would be better off trying to build a simple classifier using something like a naive bayes classifier.

Comment: I would make a Naive Bayes classifier. But the problem is I need to maintain states each state is dependent on previous state. Its time series problem and depends on a certain sequence. So here a simple classifier like Naive Bayes will not work. As far as I can understand Hidden Markov (chain) methods or something in the lines of RNN will only be feasible for this kind of problem. I am just not sure how to go about it. Thanks once again.

Comment: You don't need the state to be internal. Classify each post as one of state A,B,C,D and then do what ever it is you want with the data afterwards.

Comment: pypy in my view using hidden markov or rnn makes perfect sense in this situation. I want to utilise the previous states and based on that make a prediction. So even if it is complicated, it will be worth the efforts.